# Getting data from observables sync. Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to get data from observable. In the `subscribe()` method I can access this data. But to transfer the response to a global variable does not work. How can I do this?

**Service:**

```
getProducts():Observable<IProduct[]>{
  return <Observable<IProduct[]>> this.db.collection('products').valueChanges();
}
```

**component:**

```
products!: IProduct[];

constructor(private dataService: DataService){}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.dataService.getProducts().subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response); // return data
    this.products = response;
  })

  console.log("products: ", this.products) // return undefined
  
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("products: ", this.products) // return data
  },1000)
}
```

I tried to display data in html `*ngFor="let item of (products | async)"` but it does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your console.log will return undefined because it is executed before the subscribe is finished. Also you do not need async keyword in html when you do subscribe already. So you have to options:

```js
this.dataService.getProducts1().subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response); // return data
    this.products = response;
  });

  And in html:
  *ngFor="let item of products"
```

Or you can use observable and async keyword in html:

```js
products: Observable<IProduct[]>;

var products = this.dataService.getProducts();

  And in html:
  *ngFor="let item of (products | async)"
```

If you need to better understand why there is data in setTimeout then research Microtask and Makrotasks in Angular and in which order it is executed.

Answer (score 2):

What you did is right!

The only problem I see here is how you use it.

> console.log("products: ", this.products) // return undefined

It's expected to return `undefined` since you're logging the value but not yet set. Even though, you set the products value inside of the `subscribe` method, but take note that the Observable runs asynchronously. so, you wont get the value

If you're going to check the value of the `this.products`, you have to logged it after the code below inside of the `subscribe` callback

```
 this.dataService.getProducts1().subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response); // return data
    this.products = response;
    console.log(this.products);
  })
```

> I tried to display data in html *ngFor="let item of (products | async)" but it does not work

This won't work since your `products` is not an `observable` but rather the actual type of your data. You have to do the one below

```
*ngFor="let item of products"
```

Additional information:

If you want to use `async` pipe in your template. you have to declare this instead in your component

```
this.products = this.dataService.getProducts();
```